# Wall-in: benefit or vulnerability?

Tags: starcraft-2

In one of the [Day[9] TV videos](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3633590/) (5:40-6:00 minutes) Day[9] (what is actually his name?) says something like this:

> Wall-in is almost always a vulnearability as much as asset. In the early game wall-in off prevents rushes, but in later stages of the game it is just a ... free depo there?

Could you clarify what he said (I couldn't here the end of phrase well)?

And why it is vulnerability?

Thanks.

Comment: I made the video link clickable so it's easier to view. Thanks for including the video as a reference to interpret his meaning. :)

Comment: His name is Sean Plott.  I've talked about this across half a dozen answers, but its pretty much as you quoted.  Buildings used as walls are vulnerable.  Yes a wall is a good thing, but it has the cost of exposing those buildings to destruction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He's referring to the fact that you've placed a few supply depots and a rax right at your main base entrance. It's a vulnerability because it's 16 supply and a production building that is much easier to snipe than the rest of your supply and production buildings. **In essence, you've given your opponent what Day[9] considers to be some free buildings to destroy.**

As to whether or not its a liability, it depends on whether or not you extend your defensive perimeter to include your expansion bases.

Edit: Example of this weakness in action (playing the video will jump you to the relevant moment in the game):

Answer (score 6):

It also creates a choke in your own base, so for example if your army is in the main base while your natural expo gets attacked, it will be more difficult for you to engage the opponent, because your wall-in forces your army into a small choke.

[update]

Note: In team games (2v2 / 3v3 / 4v4), it's far more compelling to wall in because you risk facing much stronger rush attacks. The bigger the rush, the more important it is to keep them at bay while you prepare a defense. As Terran, I sometimes place unfinished buildings at the front as an emergency, or as Protoss, you sometimes need multiple zealots ready to do the hold-position gate.

[update]

A wall-in can often provide void rays an easy full-charge.

Comment: Not to mention that sometimes you forget the supply depots are raised, and order a unit to leave your base, and then 3 minutes later you're wondering why they disobeyed when they're just standing next to the depot saying "Let me out of here!" =)

Comment: just happened to me :P

Comment: Or you left behind those fat seige tanks which can't seem to fit through narrow supply depot openings at certain angles.